# How can i use normal @var inside dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

FOTOS is a table
@pathcompleto is the complete path to the file

```
set @insertvalues = 'insert into FOTOS values(@count, (SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk ''' + @pathcompleto + ''', Single_Blob) as img) , @url)'

exec(@insertvalues)
```

background:
 this is inside a loop and w other stuff but the problem is that he says @count is not declared but it is. i believe it is because of the dynamic sql (@url is also an error if i delete @count)

how do i make this work? it might work w sp_executesql but i didnt understand it that well to use it here

Answer (score 1):

You want `sp_executesql`:

```
set @insertvalues = '
insert into FOTOS
    SELECT @count, BulkColumn, @url
    FROM Openrowset( Bulk ''' + @pathcompleto + ''', Single_Blob) as img';

exec sp_executesql @insertvalues, N'@count int, @url varchar(max)',
                   @count = @count, @url = @url;
```

I also simplified the `INSERT` to be a simple `INSERT . . . SELECT`.

Note:  I don't know what the actual types are for the columns.  The above is just an educated guess.

Also, you should always include the column names when you use `INSERT` unless you really, really know why you are relying on default behavior.

Comment: ths for the change on the insert. forgot i could do that
you are right on targer w the types
new error
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

no idea what it means

Comment: finally it worked. i had to declare @insertvalues as nvarchar but i only had varchar